# I have start time 7:30 and end time 11:00 I want to get number of 11:00-7:30

Tags: vb.net-2010

how to get of time of decimal number in vb.net
example i have

*end time*: `11:00:00`

*start time*: `7:30:00`

and then I want to get value from `11:00:00 - 7:30:00` = 3,5

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract two datetimes so that you get a TimeSpan and then use the function totalHours like this:

```
Dim startTime As New DateTime(2013, 9, 19, 7, 30, 0)     ' 7:30 AM
Dim endTime As New DateTime(2013, 9, 20, 11, 0, 0)     ' 11:00 AM

Dim duration As TimeSpan = endTime - startTime     'Subtract start time from end time

Console.WriteLine(duration.totalHours);
```

Comment: +1. That's a better example.

Comment: Please flag it as the solution by pressing the 'v' under the vote cast if you found this answer to answer your question.